# SQL Stored Procedure is Classic ASP causing w3wpexe to max

Tags: sql, iis, vbscript, asp-classic

I'm working with classic ASP, vbscript and a SQL Server database.  I'm rolling out a change to several site where instead of doing multiple calls back and forth between the server and the database, we do all of the processing in a stored proc on the database server.  On the last customer site I tried this on, when the page loads, the w3wk.exe (IIS worker) process maxes the CPU to 100%, and sits. Nothing frees the CPU except a full IISReset. There is a SQL call prior to the stored proc call that works.  If I run the stored procedure directly on the database server in SQL Analyzer, it comes back in about 4 seconds.  There is nothing in the IIS log. On the other dozen or so sites I've rolled this out on, I haven't seen this behavior.  Any ideas on what I should be checking? I'm at a total loss.  Here is the code:

```vb
Set DBObj = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
DBObj.Open(Session("SiteDSN")) 

l_sql = "select count(*) l_count " _
  & " from account_list " _
  & " where email in ('B','Y') " _
  & "   and email_address is not null "

set rs = DBObj.execute(l_sql)
'*** That one works

l_total_count = rs("l_count")

l_sql = "exec stored_proc"

if request("filter1") <> "" then
  l_param1 = request("filter1")
  l_sql = l_sql & " '"& l_param1 & "',"
else
  l_sql = l_sql & " '',"
end if


if request("filter3") <> "" then
 l_param3 = request("filter3")
 l_sql = l_sql & " '"& l_param3 & "',"
else
 l_sql = l_sql & " '',"
end if

'*** The l_sql string is "exec stored_proc '','','' on the first load"

set rs = DBObj.execute(l_sql)
```

Comment: Well, it could be due to the connection to the sql server, try setting: set arithabort on at the start off the procedure. Due to an anomaly in the default adodb connection the use of indexes are somehow blocked.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for all of the suggestions.  I would "up" the usefulness of the answers, by I do not have enough reputation on this site to do so yet.

Ultimately, I took a version of the page that I knew to be working, ripped out the site-specific customization, and added the site-specific code for the site where it wasn't working. I moved the filter checks together, then built the entire query afterward.  This worked for some reason.  My only explanation is that it was caused by some subtle little scripting error - an extra space, or a special character that passed all of the syntax checks but broke the actual DB call.  As always, with a script language, sometimes rewriting that darn thing can fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple reasons why the memory is being used up too much. In classic ASP its always cleaner to configure extra parameters for the recordset and connection object, such as time-outs to prevent queries to run forever (if the stored procedure is caught in an endless loop for example). You should also **CLOSE** and then **DESTROY** each object after you are done using them.

IIS is supposed to do that automatically, but reality has shown that this is not always the case. Destroying the objects yourself ensures that it is really done for sure.

Here is a typical example code that opens a disconnected Recordset for reading only, looping over all records and then closing and destroying all objects.

```vb
Const adOpenStatic = 3, adUseClient = 3

Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
rs.cursorlocation = adUseClient 
Set DBObj = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

'Setting Timeouts in Seconds
DBObj.ConnectionTimeout = 1000
DBObj.CommandTimeout = 1000
DBObj.Open Session("SiteDSN")
rs.open l_sql, DBObj, adOpenStatic
If Not rs.EOF Then
  Set rs.ActiveConnection = Nothing
  While Not rs.EOF

  .. processing data ...

    rs.MoveNext
  End While
End If
'Cleaning Up and Releasing Resources    
rs.Close : Set rs = Nothing
DBObj.Close : Set DBObj = Nothing
```

Comment: He's reusing the same objects so can't see that being the problem, would just make sure you close off your `DBObj` using `Call DBObj.Close()` and `Set DBObj = Nothing` to release the memory it was using as Carsten suggests no need for the other stuff.

Answer (score -1):

Here are same example functions that are ready to use and should work fine. The code was tested on web clusters with 5+ web servers and several thousand concurrent users on the same site.

```vb
'---- LockTypeEnum Values ----
Const adLockReadOnly = 1
Const adLockPessimistic = 2
Const adLockOptimistic = 3
Const adLockBatchOptimistic = 4
'---- ExecuteOptionEnum Values ----
Const adAsyncExecute = &H00000010
Const adAsyncFetch = &H00000020
Const adAsyncFetchNonBlocking = &H00000040
Const adExecuteNoRecords = &H00000080
Const adExecuteStream = &H00000400
'---- CursorLocationEnum Values ----
Const adUseServer = 2
Const adUseClient = 3
'---- CursorTypeEnum Values ----
Const adOpenForwardOnly = 0
Const adOpenKeyset = 1
Const adOpenDynamic = 2
Const adOpenStatic = 3
'---- CommandTypeEnum Values ----
Const adCmdUnknown = &H0008
Const adCmdText = &H0001
Const adCmdTable = &H0002
Const adCmdStoredProc = &H0004
Const adCmdFile = &H0100
Const adCmdTableDirect = &H0200

Dim HostileAttemptString(5)
    HostileAttemptString(0) = "EXEC(@"
    HostileAttemptString(1) = "exec(@" 
    HostileAttemptString(2) = "and%201=" 
    HostileAttemptString(3) = "and%20char(" 
    HostileAttemptString(4) = "exec%28@" 
    HostileAttemptString(5) = "EXEC%28@"

Dim gsDSNString
gsDSNString = "SQL CONNECTION STRING"

'********************************************************************
'* Function: ExecSprocWithOutputParam
'* Objective: Executes stored procedure with variable amount of parameters
'   and no recordset. In addition, sproc must return one and only one output parameter
'* Input: strConnString - database connection string
'   varParamArray - Variant containing array of parameters to pass to sproc
'       Must be in exact order that sproc needs them starting from zero (0)
'   strSprocName - name of stored procedure
'* Output: Variant (output parameter value)
'********************************************************************
Function ExecSprocWithOutputParam(ByVal varParamArray, ByVal strSprocName) 'as variant
    Dim objCmd 'as object
    Dim objConn 'as object
    Dim intCounter 'as integer
    Dim intOutputIndex 'as integer

    intOutputIndex = 0
    Set objCmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    Set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    objConn.Open gsDSNString

    With objCmd
        Set .ActiveConnection = objConn
        .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
        .CommandText = strSprocName

        'Get parameter info from database - need to do this to allow output parameter
        .Parameters.Refresh

        'Start parameters at 1 since 0 is return value which we're not using
        For intCounter = 0 To UBound(varParamArray)
            .Parameters(intCounter + 1).Value = varParamArray(intCounter)

            'Add 2 to get output parameter index because array started at zero and parameters started at 1,
            'and this parameter is in addition to the paramater array passed in
            intOutputIndex = intCounter + 2
        Next

        .Execute , , adExecuteNoRecords

        'Return single output parameter
        'ExecSprocWithOutputParam = .Parameters(intOutputIndex).Value
        ExecSprocWithOutputParam = .Parameters(0).Value
        Set .ActiveConnection = Nothing
    End With

    'Clean up
    objConn.Close
    Set objConn = Nothing
    Set objCmd = Nothing
End Function

'********************************************************************
'* Function: ExecSprocWithParams
'* Objective: Executes stored procedure with variable amount of parameters
'   and no recordset.
'* Input:
'       varParamArray - Variant containing array of parameters to pass to sproc
'           Must be in exact order that sproc needs them starting from zero (0)
'       strSprocName - name of stored procedure
'* Output: None
'********************************************************************
Sub ExecSprocWithParams(ByVal varParamArray, ByVal strSprocName) 'as variant
    Dim objCmd 'as object
    Dim objConn 'as object
    Dim intCounter 'as integer
    Dim intOutputIndex 'as integer

    Set objCmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    Set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

    objConn.Open gsDSNString

    With objCmd
        Set .ActiveConnection = objConn
        .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
        .CommandText = strSprocName

        'Get parameter info from database - need to do this to allow output parameter
        .Parameters.Refresh

        'Start parameters at 1 since 0 is return value which we're not using
        For intCounter = 0 To UBound(varParamArray)
            .Parameters(intCounter + 1).Value = SQLScrub(varParamArray(intCounter))
        Next

        .Execute , , adExecuteNoRecords

        Set .ActiveConnection = Nothing
    End With

    'Clean up
    objConn.Close
    Set objConn = Nothing
    Set objCmd = Nothing
End Sub

'********************************************************************
'* Function: ExecSprocWithReturnValue
'* Objective: Executes stored procedure with variable amount of parameters
'   and no recordset. Returns return value parameter from sproc.
'* Input: 
'   varParamArray - Variant containing array of parameters to pass to sproc
'       Must be in exact order that sproc needs them starting from zero (0)
'   strSprocName - name of stored procedure
'* Output: int (return value of parameter value)
'********************************************************************
Function ExecSprocWithReturnValue(ByVal varParamArray, ByVal strSprocName) 'as variant
    Dim objCmd 'as object
    Dim objConn 'as object

    Dim intCounter 'as integer
    Dim intOutputIndex 'as integer

    Set objCmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    Set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

    objConn.Open gsDSNString

    With objCmd
        Set .ActiveConnection = objConn
        .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
        .CommandText = strSprocName

        'Get parameter info from database - need to do this to allow output parameter
        .Parameters.Refresh

        'Start parameters at 1 since 0 is return value which we're not using
        For intCounter = 0 To UBound(varParamArray)
            .Parameters(intCounter + 1).Value = varParamArray(intCounter)

            'Add 2 to get output parameter index because array started at zero and parameters started at 1,
            'and this parameter is in addition to the paramater array passed in
            'intOutputIndex = intCounter + 2
        Next

        .Execute , , adExecuteNoRecords

        'Return sproc return value
        ExecSprocWithReturnValue = .Parameters("@RETURN_VALUE").Value

        Set .ActiveConnection = Nothing
    End With

    'Clean up
    objConn.Close
    Set objConn = Nothing
    Set objCmd = Nothing
End Function

'********************************************************************
'* Function: ExecSprocGetOutputParam
'* Objective: Executes stored procedure with variable amount of parameters
' and no recordset. In addition, sproc must return one and only one output parameter
'* Input: strConnString - database connection string
' varParamArray - Variant containing array of parameters to pass to sproc
'  Must be in exact order that sproc needs them starting from zero (0)
' strSprocName - name of stored procedure
'* Output: Variant (output parameter value)
'********************************************************************
Function ExecSprocGetOutputParam(ByVal strSprocName, ByVal varParamArray) 'as variant
 Dim objCmd 'as object
 Dim objConn 'as object
 Dim intCounter 'as integer
 Dim intOutputIndex 'as integer

 Set objCmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
 Set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

 objConn.Open gsDSNString

 With objCmd
     Set .ActiveConnection = objConn
     .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
     .CommandText = strSprocName

  'Get parameter info from database - need to do this to allow output parameter
  .Parameters.Refresh

  'Start parameters at 1 since 0 is return value which we're not using
  For intCounter = 0 To UBound(varParamArray)
   .Parameters(intCounter + 1).Value = varParamArray(intCounter)

   'Add 2 to get output parameter index because array started at zero and parameters started at 1,
   'and this parameter is in addition to the paramater array passed in
   intOutputIndex = intCounter + 2
  Next

  .Execute , , adExecuteNoRecords

  'Return single output parameter
  ExecSprocGetOutputParam = .Parameters(intOutputIndex).Value

  Set .ActiveConnection = Nothing
 End With

 'Clean up
 objConn.Close
 Set objConn = Nothing
 Set objCmd = Nothing
End Function



'********************************************************************
'* Function: RSFromSproc
'* Objective: Returns recordset from call to stored procedure that takes any amount of parameters
'* Input: strConnString - database connection string
'   varParamArray - Variant containing array of parameters to pass to sproc
'       Must be in exact order that sproc needs them starting from zero (0)
'       Leave parameter blank if there are no parameters in sproc
'   strSprocName - name of stored procedure to use
'* Output: ADO Recordset
'********************************************************************
Function RSFromSproc(ByVal varParamArray, ByVal strSprocName) 'as object
    Dim objCmd 'as object
    Dim objConn 'as object
    Dim objRS 'as object

    Set objCmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    Set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set objRS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    objConn.Open gsDSNString

    With objCmd
        Set .ActiveConnection = objConn
        .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
        .CommandText = strSprocName

        objRS.CursorLocation = adUseClient
        objRS.CursorType = adOpenForwardOnly
        objRS.LockType = adLockReadOnly

        'Not using Set objRS so recordcount/absolute page properties will work.
        .Execute , varParamArray
        objRS.Open objCmd

        Set .ActiveConnection = Nothing
    End With

    Set RSFromSproc = objRS

    'Clean up
    Set objRS = Nothing
    Set objConn = Nothing
    Set objCmd = Nothing
End Function
'----------------- Support Functions -------------------------------
Function SQLScrub(ByVal val)
   Dim str,rtnVal
   rtnVal = val
   rtnVal = Replace(val,"'","''")

   For Each str in HostileAttemptString
    rtnVal = Replace(rtnVal,str,"")
   Next

   SQLScrub = rtnVal 
 End Function
```

Comment: Consider [Using `METADATA` to Import DLL Constants](http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/110199-1.shtml). Best approach is setting it as the first line of the `global.asa` which makes the constants available to the whole web application and makes constant declarations you are using in this code snippet redundant.